# How to copy the iPhone UDID on macOS Catalina?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, app-store-connect, itunes-store

How to copy UDID of the iPhone?

[image: Finder screenshot]

I want to register my iPhone as a tester within the Apple store account.
So followed the steps as per the above image.

But there is no way exist to copy the UDID and direct copy option, I can able to get only half UDID.
Please check below image:

[image: App Store Connect webpage screenshot]

How to get full UDID copy in text form? So I can paste at the Apple store account.

Comment: Just left click below the device name till you get UDID then right click on top of the UDID and copy option appears click on that that's it .  Here is what copied for me when I did the same **Serial: F72VGYONJC69 · UDID: 91298d1ad6a522d06f193a5b5762a831f7330bb1 · Model: iPhone10,4** I'm using mac 10.15.1. What's the version you are using ? I recommend you to upgrade to the latest one

Comment: I hope you saw my above example - both screenshots - what is happening with me!!

Comment: The system can't able to copy full length of code - I don't know - UDID remain half always.

Comment: What gets copied is more than the UDID. You need to paste what you copied into a temporary file or something. Then copy just the UDID value so you can paste just the UDID into iTunes Connect.

Comment: Okay I figured this out :) I have pasted this into some text file and full string appear - it may be Device ID string length that creating a problem.

Comment: @rmaddy please post your comment as the answer.

Comment: Right. You are trying to copy more than UDID into iTunes Connect so it gets truncated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you right-click on the UDID in Finder and select Copy, it actually copies the entire line so the clipboard has a string along the lines of:

> Serial: G52VGYOEJC69 · UDID: 71398d1ad6b522d06d192a5b5762a831c7730bb1 · Model: iPhone10,4

You can't paste that whole string into App Store Connect. So paste what you copied into a temporary text file or anywhere you can copy text. Then select just the actual UDID number (e.g. `71398d1ad6b522d06d192a5b5762a831c7730bb1`) and then you can copy that and paste it into the UDID field in App Store Connect.

Comment: Apple should detect this and automatically extract the UUID.

Answer (score 13):

For some reason, it doesn't show UDID in Finder (MacOS Catalina) as shown above. What works in my case is obtaining UDID using Xcode.

1. Open Xcode while having iPhone connected via USB
2. Menu > Window > Devices and Simulators [Shift+CMD+2]
3. You will see your device with **Identifier** field

[image]

Comment: just press on subtitle below and it will change the info

Answer (score 10):

you can find the UDID when you connect your iPhone to your macOS Catalina Mac:

=> Finder

=> Select you iPhone in the sidebar

=> Tab 'General'

=> Click on the text that is shown below your device name

[image]

Answer (score 5):

if for some reason udid not shown for you, just press on subttitle below the name and it will appear. hope it helps
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In catalina 10.15.5, we can select one of the long numbers to copy. Option is available now. When you right click on UDID you get the option to select what we need to copy. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You copy the UDID from the finder window, right-click on the UDID string and the option copy All, copy serial number, copy UDID, copy model option will be there. You can copy whatever you want and use it.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to find your iPhone’s UDID **without iTunes**

- First, connect your iPhone to your Mac.
- Now, click on the Apple logo at the top right and select About This Mac.
- Next, click System Report
- From the Hardware section, click USB
- Next up, click on the connected iPhone.
- Check out the **Serial Number label**. Copy the number next to it and paste it into a note. Now, **add a – (hyphen) after the 8th digit**.

Let’s say, the serial number looks like: 000011114567899. When you include the hyphen, it will be: 00001111-4567899. It’s your iPhone’s UDID.

[Source](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-find-iphone-udid-number/)

Answer (score 0):

**Update :** Apple has now fixed this problem. You can copy just UDID also.